# How does dark matter interact with light?

Tags: dark-matter, weak-interaction

Most articles I read say that dark matter are *[weakly interacting particles.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_interacting_massive_particles)* Are there any theories on how dark matter may interact with light/electromagnetic radiation?

Comment: Non-baryonic dark matter (be it WIMPs or other things) is *defined* by it's non-interaction with light.